# Aptana Open Resource Key Binding

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana3

The default keyboard shortcut for open resource in Eclipse is Ctrl+Shift+R. It is also the case in Aptana, but there also seems to be a conflicting key since when clicked it brings up a context menu with 2 options "Run" and "Open Resource". How to I avoid having this context menu pop up?

I tried to go to the preferences and look for conflicting key-bindings but I could not find it. I am also not sure what "Run" command is actually bound (I tried searching based on the key combination, that did not seem to have worked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems to me that what you want is to edit Aptana's Ruble files

take a look at [Modifying the Built-In Bundles](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys#Modifyingyourshortcutkeys-Instructions%28RublebasedCommands%29) 
and also [Ruble specifications](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Ruble+Specification) might help.

By the way, Aptana stores rubles in a directory called "Aptana Rubles", which you'll find in your user Documents directory (on Mac or Linux) or in your "User" directory (Windows)

Tutorial with more details here: [Editing Aptana Key Shortcuts and rebinding commands such as open resource](http://bunwich.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/editing-aptana-key-shortcuts-and.html)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I did find that directory there, and assumer you can use the Aptana Rubles dir to override default behaviour, I am just not sure what Ruble and how to do it exactly.

I was also hoping for a simpler, less involved solution.

Comment: sorry, i don't know much more than what i already wrote. maybe this will help. 
http://bunwich.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/editing-aptana-key-shortcuts-and.html

Answer (score 2):

An alternative fix to fix is to use a 'Cmd+T' key instead.

I familiar with Cmd+Shift+R too, but Cmd+T is a quick fix. Hope this help someone who comes across this.

Comment: Yeah ReSharper also uses this key too. But I am so used to the other key. Thanks for the tip :).